# как сделать генерацию объектов от градуса?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

суть моей проблемы находится в том, что я не могу понять как сделать генерацию "платформы" по радиусу (или градусу, я их не особо отличаю).
вот как примерно оно должно выглядеть:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
(45 градусов я взял для примера)
а вот мой код, который работает не так как надо:

```
        def pl(x,y):
            pf1 = block(x,y)
            entities.add(pf1)
            blocks.append(pf1)

        def no(x,y,rasx,rasy,w,s,s2,el):
            ddd=0
            while ddd < el:

                if x>=rasx+s:
                    y-=w
                    rasx+=s

                if y>=rasy+s2:
                    x=x-w
                    rasy+=s2
                x=x+w
                y=y+w
                pl(x,y)
                ddd+=1
#ddd - это кол - во условно имеющихся "блоков"

x,y=100,100        
no(x,y,3,5,3,250,30,100)
```

rasx - это расстояние по х (с какого момента начнётся вычислене по х)

rasy - это расстояние по у (с какого момента начнётся вычислене по у)

w - это ширина квадрата

s - это расстояние по х ( if х >= х+s: у+=w; x+=s)

s2 - это расстояние по у ( if у >= у+s2: у+=w; у+=s2)

el - количество "болков".

Вместо "no" может быть любое другое имя.

В функции "pl" просто происходит "создание" "платформы"

В функции "no" происходят вычисления (кривые), которым я не очень рад.

прошу помогите мне, я, конечно, понимаю что это может быть сложно, но это для меня важно и определит буду ли я дальше работать над своим проектом.

Comment: Так по радиусу (окружности) или по градусу (прямой)?

Comment: И хорошо бы не полениться и дать описание своего кода, в частности, что за функция `no` и её аргументы, особенно `rasx`, `s`, `s2`, `el`? А ещё лучше было бы сразу использовать более осмысленные наименования.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По определению sin и cos имеем:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в нашей задаче нужно это немного подкорректировать, т.к. точка (0, 0) соответствует верхней левой точке экрана. (Проще говоря, Oy идёт сверху вниз)

Таким образом, составляем код:

```
import math
def gen_platform_by_angle(x0:int, y0:int, alpha:int, r:int):
"""Generate one platform, on distance r from (x0, y0)"""
   x1 = x0 + int(r*math.cos(alpha))
   y1 = y0 + int(r*math.sin(alpha))
   pl(x1, y1)
   return (x1, y1) #Функция возвращает координаты новой платформы
```

Теперь будем рекурсивно вызывать эту функцию:

```
def gen_platforms_by_angle(x0:int, y0:int, alpha:int, r:int, q:int):
   for i in range(1, q+1):
      x0, y0 = gen_platform_by_angle(x0, y0, alpha, r)
```

Такая функция q раз создаст платформу, начиная с (х0, у0), на расстоянии r друг от друга.

Учитывая положение (0, 0), в переменной alpha должно содержаться -alpha, если бы мы считали в "математической" системе координат.

Comment: спасибо за помощь! а вы можете подсказать как можно сделать, чтобы "платформы" строились от произвольного угла, а не только от 45 градусов?

Comment: В мою функцию вместо 45 подставить другой произвольный угол.

Comment: ясно, большое спасибо!